# ActionBar, I want to Intent Activity within the same screen while on Action item click event.

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using Action Bar, I want to load Another Activity on action item click event **in the same screen**, not in another screen. Below in the image mentioned "Here".

[image]

On Click **Login** an LoginActivity gets intent and appears on another screen. I want to display LoginActivity content within the same screen, as mentioned above in the image.

Comment: you can use fragmentactivity

Comment: Use fragment. Replace current fragment to login fragment.

Comment: Use a Viewgroup and attach/dettach a fragment. Fragment is what you need

Comment: @  Raghunandan, now i am using Fragments, When i Intent to LoginActivity, It again jump to new Screen , as well as appears in the same screen, two things happened

Comment: Shabbir Dhangot@ i am using Fragment, But when Intent to LoginActivity, it jump to another screen. I can replace current Fragment with login fragment, after LoginActivity invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html).

If you don't want to use Fragments you can try to use a singleTop (`android:launchMode="singleTop"`) Activity and overwrite `onNewIntent()`.

The new Intent will be delivered to the currently open Activity instance.